# In laravel 4, using eloquent, is there a tidy way to include a pivot table field in the parent model's object?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Currently, the model JSONifies like:

```
"event": 
{
    "id": 3,
    "guid": "17fca759-e0b0-0692-0153-30125231b135",
    ~~snip~~
    "pivot": {
        "company_id": 1,
        "event_id": 3,
        "job_number": "31310"
    }
}
```

I'd like some way to easily move the `job_number` field into the main `event` object so that it returns flat.

We can work around it, but it'd be super groovy to clean up that return object a little. The front end doesn't need to know about that relationship type, they just need to know within the given context, what the job number is.

**Addendum**

Alternately (and a long shot), is there a way for a model to access its own pivot table? (Using a mutator)

**Solution**

With delmadord's help, the final output is along the lines of:

```
"events":
{
    "id": 3,
    "guid": "17fca759-e0b0-0692-0153-30125231b135",
    ~~snip~~
    "job_number": "31310"
},
```

By creating a mutator `getJobNumberAttribute()` that returns `$this->relations['pivot']->job_number`, setting `$appends = ['job_number']` and `$hidden = ['pivot']` to clean up the response object. Completely happy with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_dot()` [helper function](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#arrays) might be handy for the first question. It would be used *after* the eager loading with `with()` or `load()` function.

Also, from the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables), accessing the model's pivot table is possible:

```
$user = User::find(1);

foreach ($user->roles as $role)
{
    echo $role->pivot->created_at;
}
```

You should be able to access the the pivot from within the model as `$this->relation->pivot` in the same fashion, assuming that the pivot table is migrated and belongsToMany() relation is working.

**EDIT**

It appears that accessing the pivot model within the model is done by `$this->relations['pivot']->property`

Comment: ```array_flatten()``` would break on ```->with()``` and ```->load()```, wouldn't it?

Comment: And I'd like to access the pivot table from *within* the model in some way. I feel that is going require passing in the related model or its id, which seems goes against the 'tidy' intent. I was hoping for something magical: if I load an Event via a relationship to Company (```$companies->events()->get()->each(...``` or some such), I was hoping there'd be some way for the event to be aware of the company and relationship from within itself.

Comment: Marked as accepted even though it wasn't quite right. I had to call ```$this->relations['pivot']->job_number``` to access it, but it definitely pointed me in the right direction. I'd either edit your post or explain why it's different.

Comment: Thanks, although I do not have the explanation for that yet. I included your findings in the answer and upvoted your question as well.

Comment: Actually, after all that, this doesn't quite do what I was hoping for. It always returns the first result of the relationship, not the relevant one, so it's actually completely useless to me. /sigh

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? I have set up a M:M relationship, I might try that too.

Comment: And actually, **sigh**, it's been one of those days. It does work, database got twisted a bit. Thanks again for the nudge

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with accessor + appends or simple select:

```
$model = Model::with(['events' => function ($q) {
   $q->select('YOUR_PIVOT_TABLE.job_number');
}])->first();

// then it's accessible as ordinary properties:

$model->events->first()->toJson();
"event": 
{
    "job_number": "31310",
    "id": 3,
    "guid": "17fca759-e0b0-0692-0153-30125231b135",
    ~~snip~~
    "pivot": {
        "company_id": 1,
        "event_id": 3,
        "job_number": "31310"
    }

}
```

Accessor works like mentioned before, but you need to check whether it's in relation context (ie pivot is there):

```
// Event model
public function getJobNumberAttribute()
{
   return (count($this->pivot)) ? $this->pivot->job_number : null;
}
```